# Computer chess endgame

Tags: engines, endgame

Again , this is an interesting position I need help to solve. In a game Stockfish vs Ethereal , Stockfish was ahead , but Ethereal could have found  refuge in the following endgame. Is the position winning for White anyway? Could Black steer it into a positional draw?

```
[White "Stockfish"]
[Black "Ethereal"]
[FEN "4b3/4N1k1/3R3p/r7/8/P6P/5KP1/8 b - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: http://bernd.bplaced.net/fengenerator/fengenerator.html. <<<may be of benifit

Comment: white or black to move?

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure what version of Stockfish you were using so I ran analysis 12 times; 4 seperate engines for each version of Stockfish.

- Stockfish 10 vs ( Ethereal , Komodo, LC0 , Stockfish 12 )
- Stockfish 11 vs ( Ethereal , Komodo, LC0 , Stockfish 12 )
- Stockfish 12 vs ( Ethereal , Komodo, LC0 , Stockfish 12 )

Results were Stockfish (white) at the end of 20+ moves, was in a stronger position in all 9 instances. Based off this, I would suggest black is in a losing and in a irrecoverable position. There is the potential for a draw but it appears extremely unlikely.

The best variation / playout that I saw, that had the best end position for black, was Stockfish 12 vs Stockfish 12. +-3.03 / 41 so white is decisively better.

Issue with engine games in these sort of positions are the gameplay is boring. That being said, I have attached it for reference though.

```
[White "Stockfish 12"]
[Black "Stockfish 12"]
[FEN "4b3/4N1k1/3R3p/r7/8/P6P/5KP1/8 b - - 0 1"]

1... h5 2. Rd3 Kh6 3. Kg1 Kg7 4. Rc3 Kf7 5. Nc8 Kf6 6. Nd6 Bg6 7. Kh2 Ra4 8. Rf3+ Kg5 9. Nb5 Kh6 10. Nc7 Ra5 11. Ne6 Bf5 12. Re3 Bg6 13. Rc3 Bf7 14. Nf4 Kg5 15. Ne2 Ra4 16. Rf3 Bg6 17. Rg3+ Kh6 18. Rc3 Be4 19. Nf4 Ba8 20. Ne6 Ra5 21. Nc5 Bd5 22. Nd3 Ra4 23. Nb4 Be4 24. Re3
```

From my experience with engine games this is going to continue on for some time. Eventually the Black h pawn and Whites a pawns will go (will likely also involve trading out the bishops somewhere ) , white with the pawn advantage will promote.

Answer (score -1):

this would be tough to win OTB  with many ways to end up drawn

a computer might do it but I doubt it would be quick and easy